# python i need to not repeated words in a while loop

Tags: python

I need not to get the words again once its displayed using `random.choice`,

[this is the problem it shouldnt repeated words because the words have been already used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Udc.png)

I tried to delete the word using list.remove but It doesn't work and i didn't get any results

```
import random

a = ["hello", "carls", "theme", "threw", "folks", "dime", "blondie", "ocean"]
c = True
while c:
    c = input("")
    filtered_list = []
    for word in a:
      if c.upper() in word:
        filtered_list.append(word)

    if len(filtered_list) > 0:
        words = random.choice(filtered_list)
        print(words)
    else:
        print(f"there are any words with {c} or all the words have been used")
```

Comment: Explain why you are converting the input to Uppercase  ?  `c.upper()`

Comment: What do you think *if c.upper() in word* is going to achieve? Also, you should probably re-word your question. As it is it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, your requirement is once the word displayed, it will not displayed again. So delete the word from the list `a` once you get the value from `random.choice` , so that you won't get the word again or **maintain another list which holds the value already shown**

```
import random

a = ["hello", "carls", "theme", "threw", "folks", "dime", "blondie", "ocean"]
already_show = []
c = True
while c:
    c = input("Enter Letter to search:")
    filtered_list = []
    for word in a:
      if c in word:
        filtered_list.append(word)

    if len(filtered_list) > 0:
        words = random.choice(filtered_list)
        if words not in already_show:
            already_show.append(words)
            print(words)
        else:
           print("random.choice selected the already selected word")
        already_show = [] #Reset for another search
    else:
       print(f"there are any words with {c} or all the words have been used")
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure the original message of the example to solve; but i tried this

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random

a = ["hello", "carls", "theme", "threw", "folks", "dime", "blondie", "ocean"]
c = True
while c:
    c = input("")
    print("a ", a)
    filtered_list = []
    for word in a:
        if c.lower() in word:
            a.remove(word)
            filtered_list.append(word)

    if len(filtered_list) > 0:
        words = random.choice(filtered_list)
        print(words)
    else:
        print(f"there are any words with {c} or all the words have been used")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another list for `used` words:

```
from random import choice

a = ["hello", "carls", "theme", "threw", "folks", "dime", "blondie", "ocean"]

used = []
while c := input('').lower():
    filtered_list = [word for word in a if c in word and word not in used]
    if filtered_list: used += [words := choice(filtered_list)]; print(words)
    else: print(f'there are any words with {c} or all the words have been used'); # used = []
```

Output:

```
e
ocean
e
blondie
e
threw
e
dime
e
theme
e
hello
e
there are any words with e or all the words have been used
```

You might also need to reset `used` list to empty list after reach else statement for different search input of another character or letter.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by creating a new normalised list because this code is destructive. In the question, the list contains all lowercase words but it's better to generalise

Then:

```
from random import choice

a = ["hello", "carls", "theme", "threw", "folks", "dime", "blondie", "ocean"]

acopy = [word.lower() for word in a]

while acopy:
    if (c := input('Enter a single character: ').lower()) == '?':
        print(acopy)
    elif len(c) == 1:
        if possibles := [i for i, word in enumerate(acopy) if c in word]:
            print(acopy.pop(choice(possibles)))
        else:
            print(f'There are no words containing {c}')
```

As written, the while loop will only terminate when the *acopy* list is empty. You might want to do something else such as empty input.

Bonus: Enter ? to see what's remaining in the list